# Cross Join query in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to refractor a query that has in its Select concatenation of five fields, thus

```
SELECT
   Id
   '-'
   Field_2
   '-'
   Field_3
   '-'
   Field_4
    AS id
 FROM some_table
```

Example result would be something like this

```
Id

1-a-b-c-d

2-e-f-g-h

#null#
#null#
```

My problem is whilst this query works, some or all of these fields could be null. It has been suggested that a cross join could be to allow a display of null when all or any of these fields are null. Unfortunately, I am not sure how to do this. The cross join has been suggested for performance due to the large number of rows.

Can someone please show me how

Comment: A cross join seems like a strange way to do this. Just wrap each column with `Coalesce(columnname, '')` when concatenating to switch it from null to blank so it will concatenate without returning a NULL. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the issue though.

Comment: The concatenation is displaying the results as key, but in the event when something is null we still want to show the row with the Id as null in text. The query is going to be used in a mi report

Comment: No when any of the fields we show the  key as null with the word null

Comment: Again some sample data and desired results would REALLY help here.

Comment: Your code is not valid SQL.  Do you intent to have `||` between the values?

Comment: Given an example output

Comment: @JNevill `'a' || NULL` will give `a`, not `null`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't give a lot of detail but I expect what you want is the following.

```
SELECT COALESCE(Id,'') || '-' || 
       COALESCE(Field_2,'') || '-' ||
       COALESCE(Field_3,'') || '-' ||
       COALESCE(Field_4,'')
    AS id
 FROM some_table
```

Answer (score 0):

try this
select nvl(concat(concat(concat(concat(a,b),c),d),e),'NULL') from some_table

Comment: If only there was a concatenation operator ;)

Answer (score 0):

> when any of the fields we show the key as null with the word null

What could be joined here? Use simple `case`:

```
with sample_data(id, field1, field2, field3, field4) as (
    select 1,  'a',  'b',  'c',  'd' from dual union all
    select 2,  'e',  'f',  'g',  'h' from dual union all
    select 3,  'p',  'q', null,  's' from dual union all
    select 4, null,  'x',  'y',  'z' from dual )

select case when id is null or field1 is null or field2 is null or field3 is null or field4 is null
            then '#null#'
            else id || '-' || field1 || '-' || field2 || '-' || field3 || '-' || field4
       end as id
  from sample_data
```

Result:

```
ID
---------
1-a-b-c-d
2-e-f-g-h
#null#
#null#
```